# Ansible loop using ansible_hostnames

Tags: loops, ansible, apache-nifi

I'm trying to update a configuration file for a NiFi deployment, the inital deployment configuration needs to include the nodes to allow HTTPS connections to be established between them.

I have an ansible tasks that makes the required structural changes to the configuration files, but I can't seem to get the right details inserted.

```
- name: Add each host to the authorizers.xml
  lineinfile:
    path: /opt/nifi/conf/authorizers.xml
    line: "<property name=\"Node Identity {{ item }}\">CN={{ item }}, OU=NiFi</property>"
    insertafter: <!--accessPolicyProvider Node Identities-->
  loop: "{{ query('inventory_hostnames', 'nifi') }}"
```

This puts the ip addresses for the hosts, and I need to get the ansible_hostname for each node instead.
I've played around with ansible_play_batch and loop: "{{ groups['nifi'] }}" but I'm getting the result, outputting the ip addresses instead of the short hostnames each time.

The short hostnames are not stored in my ansible configuration anywhere, they are (if I understand correctly) determined at run time via the gathering facts process. I'd really like to not have to put the node names into a list variable.

Comment: what you get if you loop over the `hostvars['inventory_hostname']` variable?

Comment: See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question with minimal complete details on how to reproduce the problem. Add minimal 1) inventory 2) authorizers.xml 3) expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Get the ansible_hostname for each node"*

A: Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[nifi]
10.1.0.51
10.1.0.52
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: nifi
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [10.1.0.51] => 
  ansible_hostname: test_01
ok: [10.1.0.52] => 
  ansible_hostname: test_02
```

It's possible to iterate the hosts in the group and get *ansible_hostname* from the hostvars. For example, *delegate_to* localhost and *run_once*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.nifi }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```
ok: [10.1.0.51 -> localhost] => (item=10.1.0.51) => 
  msg: test_01
ok: [10.1.0.51 -> localhost] => (item=10.1.0.52) => 
  msg: test_02
```